# Take ill and feeling sick

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between the sentences - He was taken ill and he is feeling sick.

Answer (score 1):

The first is in the past tense, he became ill earlier on, may or may not still be ill.The second is the present tense, he is feeling sick now. The first is a more formal style, the second more direct. He himself feels sick, but this is not the opinion of an implied third party in the first example. He may not actually be sick.